# Copy & paste dynamic ranges underneath last row in other sheet & downfill date

Tags: excel, vba, range

I started using macro's very recently, so I am even below beginners level. I have a problem where I'm struggling with for days now..

here I go:

Basically I made a code to **copy 2 dynamic ranges** (columns B and K, from a pivot on sheet "FIFO list") and paste them underneath the last row with data into the sheet "FIFO tracker" in columns B and C. I handle them as 2 copy/paste operations in my code.

In column A of sheet "FIFO tracker" I want to add a **date** (just the date of today, I am running the file daily) and to downfill this date until the lastrow with data which I copied earlier. Unfortunately this line of my code doesn't do anything.

Now the 2 ranges are copied when I run the macro, but the 2nd paste operation pastes the data underneath the last row of the 1st paste operation. It should be pasted next to each other.

I hope someone could point me out where my mistakes are? 
all help is much appreciated... !

```
Sub Test_FIFO_Tracker()

  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow As Long

  Set copySheet = Worksheets("FIFO list")
  Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("FIFO tracker")

   LastRow = copySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

   'this operation goes well. It copies the portion of the column data of copySheet that I need to be pasted in pasteSheet
    copySheet.Range("B12:B" & LastRow).Copy
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, columnOffset:=1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    'here it pastes the portion of the column I need from copySheet, but it pastes it underneath the last line of the previous paste operation. it should paste it next to it, not underneath
    copySheet.Range("K12:K" & LastRow).Copy
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, columnOffset:=2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    'this operation doesn't do anything. Object required error. Here the date of today should be pasted and downfilled until the last row with data of column B or C (these always will have the same amount of data)
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY").FillDown


End Sub
```

Comment: `pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,` here you are telling it to go 1 row under, change that 1 for 0 or just skip the number.

Comment: my columns in pasteSheet have headers, so that's not possible